# Am I doing something wrong in setting my environment variable in vercel

Tags: reactjs, deployment, environment-variables, next.js, vercel

I have being using the vercel platform to host a couple of my projects without hitch.

But here my latest project supplying my application with **environment variables** and then I come up stuck after deployment,, while the project runs locally without fail,,, I keep getting this response any time I tried visiting the link provided by vercel after deployment

I have an environment **SERVER** variable which I set to **pave.vercel.app** equivalent to **localhost:3000** when running on my local machine

I have my next.config.js file setup like this

```
module.exports = {
   env: {
         NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER: process.env.SERVER,
         MONGODB_URL: process.env.MONGODB_URL,
      },
};
```

Am fetching my data from mongodb like this

```
    const server = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER;

      export const getData = async (url) => {
    const res = await fetch(`${server}/api/${url}`, {
      method: "GET",
       origin: "*",
          });

            const data = await res.json();

            return data;
          };
          export const postData = async (url, post) => {
                  const res = await fetch(`${server}/api/${url}`, {
                   method: "POST",
                  headers: {
                       "content-Type": "application/json",
                          },
                  body: JSON.stringify(post),
               });
              const data = await res.json();
                         return data;
                      };
```

Am suspecting after deployment is not calling the right url to fetch my data since this will be different from the default **localhost:3000** am using on local

please have being on this for the last 3 days and I need to get this project up and running as soon as possible

Any help will be highly welcomed in this regards...Thanks in Advance

Comment: "I keep getting this response any time I tried visiting the link provided by vercel after deployment" - what response do you get?

Comment: A server error has occurred
500: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
Code: FUNCTION_INVOCATION_FAILED
ID: lhr1::9ptq2-1616261468770-c55bb6d7f5b6

Comment: Where is that code for fetching data from mongodb located?

Comment: I have a getData model as seen above in my under a util directory I created in my root . Then ofcourse I have a contsruct under my api folder to return the data based on the type of request (POST or GET) . Then I am sending the request using getServerSideProps from a route under my page folder